# How to reconnect to Remote Session in a script?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, scheduled-tasks

I need to persist a Remote desktop connection across a reboot of a Terminal server. I'm thinking that it would be something like a scheduled task that would run periodically and check the running state of the session and restart it if it's down. BTW, I did check the "Reconnect..." checkbox on the advanced tab of the connection options, but it still goes down everytime we restart the terminal server.

Does anyone have the script that would accomplish the above in a scheduled task, or perhaps another solution?

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for one machine you could set up a script but if this is for multiple users I would avoid setting up anything.

For an actual script we would need more information about the systems both the workstation and remote terminal server

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to use psexec from SysInternals to restart my session for all my terminals remotelly from a central location. I use psList to check if the rdp session is still up. Thanks anyway.